# Ubuntu server 18.04 nginx crashes and reboots when testing SSL certificates

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-18.04, certbot

So far I installed ubuntu server 18.04, made the latest upgrades and dist-upgrades then I installed nginx with apt install after that I used cerbot to get the SSL certificates.

```
server {

server_name  www.example.com;

location / {
    root   /var/www/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name  www.example.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

But when testing the [SSL certificates](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) the server crashes and reboots.

I've check /var/logs but I could not find something related to the crash.

Comment: What do you mean by "testing the SSL certificates"? What exactly did you do?

Comment: I put my domain through this ssl tester https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html this is the only one I found that reboots although there are other sites for the same purpose.

Comment: Well, that's strange. What are specifications of your server?

Comment: Ubuntu server 18.04.4 - Linux 4.15.0-106-generic - nginx/1.19.0, (10cpus - 20gbs ram)

Comment: `the server (...) reboots` sound more like a defunct hardware/driver or a really nasty bug. This is not because of your vonfig. It not **that** easy to get a kernel to reboot awhole system (without dropping a line to messages or syslog.